# PHP: Comparing amounts

Tags: php, comparison, operators, constants

I have a constant with a minimum transaction amount.

```
define( 'MINIMUM_AMOUNT', 100.00 );
```

I have a function which pulls transactions from a database and prepares them for a transfer. I require the total amount of the transactions to be greater than the minimum in order to continue. Like so:

```
foreach( $merchant as $merch ) {

     ......

     foreach( $transactions as $trans ) {
          $trans_total = number_format( $trans_total + $trans->amt, 2 );
     }

     if( $trans_total < MINIMUM_AMOUNT )
          continue;

     .....

}
```

Obviously there is some code missing, but I think you see what is going on here. The issue I am having is that when I am comparing the calculated total against the constant, it is returning as `true`, even when it is not, and thus `continue` is triggered and the rest of the script doesn't run.

I have confirmed that $trans_total is greater than the MINIMUM_AMOUNT various times, attempted with various amounts, and even used `var_dump()` to check the `type` of the variables. I can't figure out what the issue is.

Any ideas? If it helps, I'm running the latest version of PHP within a LAMP environment.

NOTE:

I have tried typecasting both to float already with no luck.

Comment: Please show some example data that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Try typecasting both to float?

Comment: Have you tried without using `number_format()`? Comparing a `float` to a `string` is probably not what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why not `SUM()` up the trans_total with SQL?

Comment: @djot I could, but I need each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`number_format()` was the issue. This returns a `string`, which caused the issue with the comparison. Type casting the `$trans_total` afterwards as a `float` did not work because of the comma within the string.

Removing `number_format()` all together did the trick.

Kudos to @Pj Dietz.